# Aligning buttons inside div and span between buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, responsive-design

I have a div in which I have some 3 buttons and a span that is generated.
My questions are:

Can I align my buttons with the squares without using margins?
(The first button would be where the first square starts and the last button would be where the last square ends)

How do I align my span inside the two buttons?

```
<div id="stripe">
  <button id="new">New Colors</button>
  <span id="message"></span>
  <button id="easy">Easy</button>
  <button id="hard">Hard</button>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/frrfa4jb/)

Comment: Your question title and the last question didn't match! You want button, span, button => align; or you want align span inside button????

Comment: You're right! I wil edit it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this. You need to replace **inside** word by **between** word. The span in your case is not inside the buttons.

```css
button{
  background-color:darkblue;
  color:white;
  padding:5px 10px;
  border:none;
  font-size:20px;
}

#stripe >*{
  vertical-align:top;/*or bottom, middle....*/
}
```

```html
<div id="stripe">
  <button id="new">New Colors</button>
  <span id="message">Some message</span>
  <button id="easy">Easy</button>
  <button id="hard">Hard</button>
</div>
```